# Maximum Likelihood Estimator of scaled beta

Tags: statistics

I want to find the MLE of $X = \theta{Y}$, where $\theta > 0$ and $Y \sim \mathrm{Beta}(2,1)$. The density for $X$ is given by $$f_{\theta}(x) = \frac{2x}{\theta^{2}}$$

on $[0,\theta]$.

It has been a bit problematic finding the MLE here (for fixed $x \in [0, \theta]$, doesn't seem to be any value $\hat{\theta}$ that maximizes this function). I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/383587/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just a single observation, $X$, then $\theta$ is necessarily $\ge X$, so the decreasing function $\theta\mapsto2x/\theta^2$ has as its domain the interval $[X,\infty)$.  And there is indeed a value of $\theta$ in that domain where $\theta\mapsto2x/\theta^2$ assumes its maximum value.

If there are $n$ i.i.d. observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, then the domain is $\left[\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\},\infty\right)$.

Comment: In the case of just a single observation, is there a way to get the functional representation of the maximum likelihood estimator?

Comment: What do you mean by the functional representation?

Comment: I just meant $\hat{\theta}(x)$. The function twhich, evaluated at $x$ gives the maximizing value $\theta$ for fixed $x$.

Comment: Since the likelihood function $L(\theta)$ is decreasing on the interval $[x,\infty)$ (or $[\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ in the case of multiple observations), the maximum occurse when $\theta$ is at the left endpoint.